# Why will my MYSQL UPDATE statement not update?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<script>
function enter_edit(column)
{
var username = '<?php echo $username ;?>';
var password = '<?php echo $password ;?>';
var input = prompt("Please enter a new " + column , "");
//window.alert(input);
//window.alert(column);
//window.alert(username);
//window.alert(password);
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_account.php",
        data: { input:input , username:username , password:password, column:column }

    });
window.alert("Account has been edited");
window.location = 'manage_account.php';
}
</script>
```

I have this function which takes in both the username and password of the account which has already been previously queried, gets what the user wants the selected column to be changed to and so on. I send these variables to edit_account.php to do the UPDATE query. As far as i can tell all of the variables are correct when I did a window.alert() for all 4 of them.

```
<?php

    require ('connect.php');

    $input = $_POST['input'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $column = $_POST['column'];


    $link = my_connect(); 

    $editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set '".$column."' = '".$input."' where UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
    //$deleteAccount = $link->query("delete from AdvancedUser where UserName = '".$username."' AND UserPassword = '".$password."'");

    $editAccount->close();
    $link->close();


?>
```

This is edit_account.php in which i am trying to use a mysql UPDATE to make my changes however with this code it changes nothing. When i try to put in a delete query instead(just to test if my connection wasn't working) it works just fine. Any ideas? thanks again

Comment: What the hell are you printing password on the code, dude?!?!?!?! Have you ever heard about [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) ?

Comment: Security is not a top priority for this project, also this is for a admin account. So as to the passwords being there ignore them.

Comment: Looks like you have extra single quotes around your column name after "set". Those will ruin it, MySQL will consider it not a column name, but a string.

Comment: Are you talking about the prompt("Please enter a new " + column , "");?  I believe that signifies a blank string

Comment: @user3550676 No, he is talking about the query.  You don't need quotes around a column name, only the value.

Comment: @user3550676 I really hope security isn't needed for this project.  This query is subject to SQL injection and you are printing the password in the page source.

Comment: You were totally correct, i changed it to set ".$column."  and it works great and Devon security is not, thanks for the worry, however any tips or suggestions would be accepted

Comment: @Darwin My two suggestions:  (1) You should always use prepared statements when using user input (POST/GET) in SQL queries to avoid SQL injections.  (2) You should never display sensitive information in plain text on the client end.

Comment: By the way set ".$column." doesn't work, $column does, copied that wrong. Thanks again Devon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set '".$column."' = '".$input."' where UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
```

to:

```
$editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set $column = '".$input."' where UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
                                                    ^_______^--without quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php
        require ('connect.php');

        $input = $_POST['input'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $column = $_POST['column'];

        $link = my_connect(); 

        $editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set $column = '".$input."' where 
        UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
        //$deleteAccount = $link->query("delete from AdvancedUser where UserName = 
        '".$username."' AND UserPassword = '".$password."'");

        $editAccount->close();
        $link->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes surrounding $column.

Instead of this:

```
$editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set '".$column."' = '".$input."' where UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
```

Try this:

```
$editAccount = $link->query("update AdvancedUser set ".$column." = '".$input."' where UserName = '".$username."' and UserPassword = '".$password."'");
```

When you echo this query it would look like:

```
update AdvancedUser set ColumnName = 'ColumnValue' where UserName = 'username' and UserPassword = 'password'
```